# Как закрыть диалог из библиотеки BottomDialog программно?

Tags: java, android, dialog

Использую BottomDialog из библиотеки github https://github.com/shaohui10086/BottomDialog/

```
BottomDialog.create(thisA.getSupportFragmentManager())
                    .setViewListener(new BottomDialog.ViewListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void bindView(View v) {
                            initView(v);
                            // // You can do any of the necessary the operation with the view
                        }
                    })
                    .setLayoutRes(R.layout.dialog_layout)
                    .setDimAmount(0.2f)            // Dialog window dim amount(can change window background color）, range：0 to 1，default is : 0.2f
                    .setCancelOutside(true)     // click the external area whether is closed, default is : true
                    .setTag("BottomDialog") // setting the DialogFragment tag
                    .show();
```

После того как он появился, как его можно закрыть программно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BottomDialog** наследник класса **DialogFragment**, у этого класса есть метод **dismiss**
Попробуйте так:

```
BottomDialog dialog = BottomDialog.create(thisA.getSupportFragmentManager())
                .setViewListener(new BottomDialog.ViewListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void bindView(View v) {
                        initView(v);
                        // // You can do any of the necessary the operation with the view
                    }
                })
                .setLayoutRes(R.layout.dialog_layout)
                .setDimAmount(0.2f)            // Dialog window dim amount(can change window background color）, range：0 to 1，default is : 0.2f
                .setCancelOutside(true)     // click the external area whether is closed, default is : true
                .setTag("BottomDialog") // setting the DialogFragment tag
                .show()
```

и потом в нужном месте вызвать:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: большое cпасибо!